# Lua / Love2D / LÖVE script not receiving IRC messages

Tags: lua, irc, twitch, love2d

I've been trying to connect to Twitch chat IRC using Love2D. It manages to connect (`if connect == 1 then`). I'm just not sure how to receive any IRC messages that are being sent to me (`love.update()`).

```
function love.load()
    oauth = "oauth:someoauthhere"
    user = "botname"
    channel = "channeltojoin"

    love.graphics.setFont(love.graphics.newFont(32))

    socket = require("socket")
    irc = socket.tcp()
    connect = irc:connect("irc.chat.twitch.tv", 6667)
    if connect == 1 then -- MAKES IT PAST THIS
        irc_messages = {}
        irc:send("PASS " .. oauth)
        irc:send("USER " .. user)
        irc:send("JOIN #" .. channel)
    end
end

function update(dt)
    line, err = irc:receive() --> Returns nothing
    if line then
        table.insert(irc_messages, line)
    end
end

function love.draw()
    if not next(irc_messages) == nil then
        love.graphics.printf(table.concat(irc_messages, "\n"), 0, 0)
    end
end
```

Comment: what does irc:receive() return?

Comment: Nothing. I don't recieve any of them. The variables "line" and "err" are just nil.

Comment: it should at least give an error message. did you try providing any patters as listed in the documentation? http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#receive

Comment: I've tried both the `"*a"` and `"*l"` method.

Comment: irc:connect() returns [nil and an error message as the second argument](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#connect) when it encounters an error. Provide a second variable for this error, and see what it is.

Comment: Nothing is going wrong in the `irc:connect()`. _"the method returns nil followed by a string describing the error. In case of success, the method returns 1._" It returns `1`. It goes wrong at `line, err = irc:receive()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after spending a long time searching. 
Instead of this:
`connect = irc:connect("irc.chat.twitch.tv", 6667)`
I needed this:
`connect = irc:connect(socket.dns.toip("irc.chat.twitch.tv"), 6667)`